# Java 8 removeif with method reference

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I am going over some Java 8 code and observed something like below, can someone please help me understand what it actually means?

`hashSetA.removeif(hasSetB::remove);`

Comment: I think you should clear your question about what is `hashSetA` or `hashSetB` ?

Answer (score 1):

A method reference is a shorthand for passing the argument of the lambda to the method. In other words, this snippet:

```
hashSetA.removeIf(hashSetB::remove);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
hashSetA.removeIf(itemFromA -> hashSetB.remove(itemFromA));
```

[`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) returns true if an item was actually remove. So what's actually going on here is that `removeIf` goes over all the items in `hashSetA`, and attempts to remove each one from `hashSetB`. If the item actually was in `hashSetB`, it's removed from it, and then removed from `hashSetA`.

Comment: HashSet has `removeIf` since java 8 See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html from Collection https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html